# Passing data to ViewChild from component - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I pass a data from component to view child element. e.g
This the variable that I have declared on component:

```
@ViewChild('warningNotification', { static: false }) warningNotification: jqxNotificationComponent;
public test: string = "NIshan";
```

Now I have a element on html page

```
<jqxNotification #warningNotification
             [template]="'warning'"
             [blink]="false"
             [autoOpen]="false"
             [autoClose]="true"
             [closeOnClick]="true"
             [position]="'top-right'"
             [opacity]="0.9"
             [width]="'auto'">
<div><span>
        {{test}}
</span>
</div>
</jqxNotification>
```

but `{{test}}` this section not rendering any text. How can I solve this

Comment: @Exomus - I don't have `@Input` instead I have `@VIewChild` please have a look at my updated question thank you

Comment: I think you should close the tag ```<jqxNotification></jqxNotification>```

Comment: @FatemeFazli - tag is already closed

Answer (score 1):

In

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.warningNotification=this.test
}
```

NOTE: is possible you need enclosed in a setTimeout to avoid error "change after checked"

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
   setTimeout(()=>{
      this.warningNotification=this.test
   })
}
```